# finding depth of object without use of arithmetics

Tags: recursion, prolog

Without using arithmetics (=< , =>, etc.)!

I have a few separate piles of blocks, for example two piles.
I need a way to figure out if block A sits Higher on any pile than block B.

For example:

```
       is_on_top(Block1,Pile,Block2). %relations of blocks in a particular pile
```

for example:

```
         is_bellow(a,1,b). % a is bellow b in pile number 1
         is_bellow(r,2,e).
         is_bellow(f,2,null). % is at top.
         ....
         and so on.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write the predicate:

```
is_higher(Block1,Block2):-    %block1 is higher than block2 in Any line.




 % to check for the same line if a block is higher than another I'm this

 % is Block1 higher than Block2 in THE SAME pile.

taller(Block1, Block2) :-
    is_bellow(Block2,_,Block1).

taller(Block1, Block2) :-
    is_bellow(Y, I,Block1), 
    taller(Y, Block2).
```

is it possible to do it without using arithmetics?

I think I have the terminating condition.

```
is_higher(Block1,Block2):-
is_bellow(Block1,_,null), is_bellow(Block2,_,X).
X \= null.

is_higher(Block1,Block2):-  % don't know how to continue.
```

Comment: It is possible; have you made *any* attempt to solve even part of this yourself?

Comment: yes, I thought something along the lines of digging deeper on both blocks till block one is paired with null, but I cant quite get my head around it.

Comment: If I placed blocks in piles on a table, and all you were able to ask were questions about what block sits immediately on another, how would you determine if one block was above another?

Comment: yes, and those are given facts. I can even figure out if one block is higher than another in the same pile, I've done that. but for two blocks that may or may not be in separate piles I don't know.

Comment: You don't know how to tell if 2 blocks are if different piles?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you have already written, and explain what it does.

Comment: I edited the question to enter the code for the termination condition(which might be correct) not sure how to write the main body of the recursion

Comment: Block A is higher than Block B if a) A is on top of B or b) the block A is on top of is higher than B.

Comment: Where did `is_below` come from?  What happened to `is_on_top`?

Comment: I have something already that works if block A is higher that block B if they are on the same pile. my problem is that I need a way to check if block A is higher than block B even if they are on separate piles.

Comment: I edited the question to show how to check if Block1 is Higher than Block two on the same pile, thats easy and it works, but  I need help in the general case of when the blocks are on separate piles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> I thought something along the lines of digging deeper on both blocks till block one is paired with null, but I cant quite get my head around it.

You are thinking along the correct lines, but your representation of the world seems to confuse you a bit. It becomes easier if we define a cleaner language for talking about blocks and their relationships.

It would have been good if you had posted a complete example. Here is the one I will be using:

```
is_below(a, 1, b).
is_below(b, 1, null).  % topmost on pile

is_below(c, 2, d).
is_below(d, 2, e).
is_below(e, 2, f).
is_below(f, 2, null).  % topmost on pile
```

I understand this to model the following world:

```
             f
             e
  b          d
  a          c
-----------------
pile 1     pile 2
```

Now let's talk about concepts related to this world. First... what even is a block? The representation is implicit, but it appears that a block is something that is on a pile. Being "on a pile" is somewhat implicit too, but it means being below *something* -- another block, or the special non-block atom `null`.

So this is a block:

```
% block(X): X is a block
block(X) :-
    is_below(X, _Pile, _BlockOrNull).
```

Prolog can now enumerate blocks:

```
?- block(X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
X = e ;
X = f.
```

Note that `null` is not included, which is good since it is not a block.

Now, `is_below` complicates things because it talks about non-blocks (namely, `null`) and also about the numbers of piles, which we don't always need. Let's define a simpler notion of a block being directly on top of another block:

```
% block_on(X, Y): X is a block directly on top of block Y
block_on(X, Y) :-
    is_below(Y, _Pile, X),
    block(X).
```

Note that we use `block(X)` to make sure we only talk about blocks. Let's test:

```
?- block_on(X, Y).
X = b,
Y = a ;
X = d,
Y = c ;
X = e,
Y = d ;
X = f,
Y = e ;
false.
```

Good. Now, let's define notions for being the topmost and the bottommost block on a pile:

```
% top(X): X is a block that is topmost on its pile
top(X) :-
    block(X),
    \+ block_on(_OtherBlock, X).  % no other block is on X

% bottom(X): X is a block that is bottommost on its pile
bottom(X) :-
    block(X),
    \+ block_on(X, _OtherBlock).  % X is not on any other block
```

This behaves like this:

```
?- top(X).
X = b ;
X = f.

?- bottom(X).
X = a ;
X = c ;
false.
```

And *now* we can return to your comment:

> I thought something along the lines of digging deeper on both blocks till block one is paired with null, but I cant quite get my head around it.

You were talking about digging (upwards?) until you arrive at a topmost block, but in fact what you should be doing is to dig *downwards* until you arrive at a *bottommost* block! Hopefully you can see that it's easier to talk about these concepts now that we have given them clearer names, rather than descriptions like being "paired with `null`".

Let's start with a non-recursive rule for expressing "higher than". Any non-bottom block is definitely "higher than" any bottom block:

```
% higher_than(X, Y): X is a block higher on any pile than Y
higher_than(X, Y) :-
    bottom(Y),
    block(X),
    \+ bottom(X).
```

This already captures a lot of relationships:

```
?- higher_than(X, Y).
X = b,
Y = a ;
X = d,
Y = a ;
X = e,
Y = a ;
X = f,
Y = a ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = d,
Y = c ;
X = e,
Y = c ;
X = f,
Y = c ;
false.
```

Any non-bottom block (`b`, `d`, `e`, `f`) is higher than any bottom block (`a`, `c`).

Now let's do the "digging" part to express that, for example, `f` is higher than `b`. Your idea is correct: If we're at some blocks `X` and `Y`, and `X` is directly on top of some block `V` and `Y` is directly on top of some block `W`, and we can somehow establish that `V` is higher than `W`, then `X` is higher than `Y`! Here's the same idea expressed in Prolog code:

```
higher_than(X, Y) :-
    block_on(X, V),
    block_on(Y, W),
    higher_than(V, W).
```

So is `f` higher than `b`?

```
?- higher_than(f, b).
true ;
false.
```

Nice. And enumerating all "higher than" pairs:

```
?- higher_than(X, Y).
X = b,
Y = a ;
X = d,
Y = a ;
X = e,
Y = a ;
X = f,
Y = a ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = d,
Y = c ;
X = e,
Y = c ;
X = f,
Y = c ;
X = e,
Y = b ;
X = e,
Y = d ;
X = f,
Y = b ;
X = f,
Y = d ;
X = f,
Y = e ;
false.
```

Most of these are as before, but we got some new pairs as well: `e` is higher than `b` and `d`, `f` is higher than `b`, `d`, and `e`. And that is all!

Final remark: I'm not an expert on blocks worlds, but my impression was that it is more usual to model the table top as a special "location" rather than having a special marker for "there is nothing above this".

So I would have represented the same world more like this:

```
pile_on(1, a, table).
pile_on(1, b, a).

pile_on(2, c, table).
pile_on(2, d, c).
pile_on(2, e, d).
pile_on(2, f, e).
```

You could switch your code to this representation, maybe it would make your life easier. You could also keep the same `higher_than` definition -- if you adjust the definitions of `block` and `block_on`, all the rest can remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the really good explanation. unfortunately I was not allowed to use arithmetics such as =< or +/ etc. Otherwise its a great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `is_below( A, P, B)` means block `A` is immediately below block `B` in some pile `P`, or is topmost in that pile, with `B = null`, we can code the `is_higher( A, B)` predicate exactly as you wanted:

we either have one more step to go down the piles and recurse, or we've reached the bottom of the `B` pile and judge the situation accordingly:

```erlang
is_higher(           A,  B) :-  % A is higher than B, if
   is_below(  A2, _, A),        %    A is atop one
   is_below(      B2, _, B),    %    which is _higher_ than that
   A \== B,                     %    which B is atop of
   is_higher( A2, B2).          %      (determined _recursively_)

is_higher( A, B) :-             % or,
   is_below( _, _, A),          %    A is not bottommost
   is_below( B, _, _),          %    while B is, because 
   \+ is_below( _, _, B).       %      there is nothing below B

%% the world:    c
%%               b  e
%%               a  d
is_below(a,1,b).
is_below(b,1,c).
is_below(c,1,null).
is_below(d,2,e).
is_below(e,2,null).
```

Testing:

```erlang
36 ?- findall( A-B, (is_higher(A,B), A\==null), X).
X = [c-b, c-e, b-a, b-d, c-a, c-d, e-a, e-d].
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I was not allowed to use arithmetic operators us as /+ or =< etc

Comment: and where do I use any of those here? oh you mean `\+`? it is *"not"*, it means *"can't prove that..."*. it is *"negation by failure"*, not arithmetic at all.